# Issues in SharedPreference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have one button in mainactivity when i click on button formactivty opened then after saved the data and i killed the app it display from main activity, it doesn't show welcome activity by using shared preference. any one can solve this one

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void open(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Form.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

FormActivty

```
public class Form extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences sp;
    public static String Filename= "LoginFile";
    public static String key = "status";
    EditText namee,emaill;
    String Name,Email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sp = getSharedPreferences(Filename,MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean res = sp.getBoolean(key,false);
        if (res) {
            setContentView(R.layout.welcom);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.form);
        }
    }

    public void save(View v) {
        namee = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        emaill = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);

        Name = namee.getText().toString();
        Email = emaill.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
        ed.putBoolean(key,true);
        ed.putString("k1",Name);
        ed.putString("k2",Email);
        ed.commit();
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Welcome.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Welcome Activity

```
public class Welcome extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences sp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcom);
        sp = getSharedPreferences(Form.Filename,MODE_PRIVATE);
        TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        TextView tv1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        String username,email;
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b= i.getExtras();
        username = sp.getString("k1","");
        email = sp.getString("k2","");
        tv.setText(username);
        tv1.setText(email);
    }

    public void logout(View v) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
        ed.putBoolean(Form.key,false);
        ed.commit();
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You never launch the activity based on the shared preferences. You still need to click your button and open `Form`, and even the only the Welcome activity's layout will be used. It won't open it.

Comment: can u write in code format i cant understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `MainActivity`, under `onCreate()`, there should be a code that checks if your `SharedPreference` is empty. If it's empty, it should go to `Form.class` or it should not do anything since you have a button there in MainActivity. If not, then go to `Welcome.class`. You're almost there, just do some minor tweaks on your code and you'll get it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences sp;
    public static String Filename= "LoginFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sp = getSharedPreferences(Filename,MODE_PRIVATE);
        String name = sp.getString("k1", "");
        if(!name.isEmpty()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Welcome.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public void open(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Form.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

If you'll notice on this code, every time the app is killed and you start it again, it'll check if sharedpreference is empty. If not, it will go directly to `Welcome.class`.

Comment: i cant understand can u write where is my mistake in programme how to arrange

Comment: @A.asha I added codes for you to easily understand it :)

Comment: it will notice another problem when i m click on logout it doenot logout again it shows same data it doesnot open main activity when i m click on logout

Comment: @A.asha on your logout(), you should add `ed.clear()` before `ed.commit()` if you want to clear the SharedPreference. Tell me if it works.

Comment: @A.asha No problem at all! Willing to help here. If you need help, just contact me I'll try to help you :) By the way, don't forget to accept my answer by checking it! Have a good day!

Comment: please give me u r gmail i will stay in touch with u

Comment: https://codeshare.io/bd5k4 click on link.carview doesnot opened please solve this one